# How to have Activity call an method in the Fragment class if I am using Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-activity, android-navigation

I want to call a method in the Fragment class from the Activity. Using 
`getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.example_fragment)`

has been causing the error

`Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.package.name.HomeFragment.functionName()' on a null object reference`.

I think this may have to do with the fact that I am using a Navigation Drawer, so I don't directly run `getSupportFragmentManager.beginTransaction.add(fragmentStuff).commit();`, but I am unsure about how to fix this error.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add fragment in activity before calling its method.

There is two ways to find fragment and call its method:

First:

```
ExampleFragment fragment = (ExampleFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.example_fragment);

if(fragment.isAdded()){
    fragment.functionName(); 
}
```

Second:

```
ExampleFragment fragment = (ExampleFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTAG("tagofExampleFragment");

if(fragment.isAdded()){
    fragment.functionName(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I get the feeling you are treating your fragment as java class, a [fragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html) should be used as an interface.

You could try something

MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment(); 
fragment.myMethod();

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the first sentence. Isn't the fragment a java class that extends the Fragment class?